# Building freetype2. libfreetype.a is not produced

Tags: 64-bit, freetype, freetype2

I'm trying to build freetype2.
I'm using fedora 17 under x64 architecture.
When i invoke make command in freetype source directory, only libfreetype.la (along with some object files) is produced.
Why I'm missing libfreetype.a ?

On Ubuntu 11.10 and 32-bit architecture, I've compiled the same and got libfreetype.a. Is there any special procedure in x64 architectre?

Answer (score 2):

Just to be safe, delete the entire folder and uncompress the package so we know you are dealing with the original files. Then do the following:

```
./configure --enable-static
make
```

This will produce the static library.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer your last question: just yesterday I successfully compiled Freetype2 (git master, head revision) under MSYS for x86_64-w64-mingw32 with both `--enable-static` and `--enable-shared`, and it produced the static libfreetype.a just fine. I didn't do anything special, so apparently no special procedure is needed.

If you didn't specify `--enable-static` it should still be set to YES by default in recent versions of Freetype's configure script. The problem must somehow be on your end. If you haven't managed to solve it by now, I suggest you do as Dustin Juliano recommended.